# Options for many-to-many message encryption

Tags: encryption, public-key-encryption

I have a group of (approximately) 20,000 users who need to receive encrypted messages from the public.  What kind of encryption regimen should I use?

If I use PKI, I would need to share the private key with each of the 20,000 members, which is obviously a huge security risk.  What other options are there?

Comment: "I would need to share the private key" What? The private key is never shared with anyone. To encrypt a message for multiple uses, you encrypt the message with some symetric encryption scheme, and then send to each recipent the encrypted message and the symetric key encrypted with their *public* key. PGP already does that. Don't implement this yourself.

Comment: By far the easiest solution would be for the "public" to encrypt their message to your single public key, which you then decrypt and make available to your 20,000 users over a https with normal username/password authentication. This breaks end-to-end encryption, but it may be acceptable in your security model. Otherwise, do what @Peter suggests and use PGP. All 20k users must install PGP and generate their own keypair. They give you the public keys and you put them in some directory so the public has easy access to them.